# Spring cloud data flow one processor sending customs data to mutiples sinks

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

In Spring SCDF, I got one processor with just one input and I want to send data to 3 different sinks depending on data type for example: integers to sink1, Strings to Sink3 and Longs to SInk3 , each sink should be able to consume from the processor

i tried something like that.

```
@Bean
    public Function <String, Tuple3<Flux<String>,Flux<String>, Flux<String>>> sort() {
        return srt -> {
           XXXXX
           XXXXXX
            return Tuples.of(Flux.just(data1), Flux.just(data2),Flux.just(data3));


        };
    }
```

```
stream create --name test1 --definition "source  --server.port=1001 | worker || sink1 || sink2  || sink3"
```

Answer (score 0):

This example has multiple stream apps sending messages to specific outputs.

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/main/restaurant-stream-apps

You can also look at the Router Sink for inspiration. https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/tree/2021.1.x/applications/sink/router-sink